# Keras: How to slice a constant matrix with the Input tensor in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The code is like:

```
from keras.layers import Embedding, Input, Dense, Flatten, concatenate, Dot, Lambda
from keras import backend as K

def get_model(train, num_users, num_items, userlayers=[512, 64], itemlayers=[1024, 64]):
    num_layer = len(userlayers)  # Number of layers in the MLP

    # Input variables
    user_input = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32', name='user_input')
    item_input = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32', name='item_input')

    user_matrix = getTrainMatrix(train)
    user_latent_vector = K.variable(value=user_matrix[user_input, :])
    item_latent_vector = K.variable(value=user_matirx[:, item_input])

    userlayer = Dense(userlayers[0], activation="linear", name='userlayer0')
    itemlayer = Dense(itemlayers[0], activation="linear", name='itemlayer0')
    user_latent_vector = userlayer(user_latent_vector)
    item_latent_vector = itemlayer(item_latent_vector)

    prediction = Dot(1)([user_latent_vector, item_latent_vector])

    model_ = Model(inputs=[user_input, item_input], outputs=prediction)

    return model_
```

The `getTrainMatrix()` function returns a numpy matrix with rows representing users and columns representing items. This matrix should be a constant matrix which is irrelevant to the `Input` tensor. I want to get some rows or colums according to the `Input` tensor (mini-batches), i.e., `user_input` and `item_input`, and then feed the slice into a MLP. Should I convert the numpy matrix to a tensor in advance? How to slice the matrix according to the Input tensor?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should convert the matrix in a tensor, this can be simply:

```
user_matrix = K.variable(user_matrix)
```

Also, you're going to need `K.gather` or `tf.gather`. The tensorflow version is better because you can choose the axis:

```
user_latent_vector = Lambda(lambda x: K.gather(user_matrix,x))(user_input)
item_latent_vector = Lambda(lambda x: tf.gather(user_matrix,x,axis=1))(item_input)
```

Maybe you will need `Input(batch_shape=(None,),....)` to achieve this properly.

Comment: Thank you so much! The gather function is very useful but using it causes another problem, i.e., "AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'". Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @ZhihongDeng All operations must be inside layers. Updated my answer putting the operations inside layers.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. I have tried the Lambda layer, but it raised another error, i.e., “TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'indices' has DataType float32 not in list of allowed values: int32, int64”. This is so weird since nothing is explicitly declared as a float tensor. I'm very confused about why it said the passed indices parameter has float type.

Comment: The inputs (indices) must be integer, you can do that with `Input(....., dtype = 'int32')`.

Comment: Maybe `dtype=int`.

Comment: Yes, I forced the Input to has type int32, but the error still raised and that's why I'm so confused.

Comment: Everything is float by default. Did you explicitly change the type of both the "input tensors" and the numpy array?

Comment: Yes. I have forced the Input tensor and user_matrix to be int32. I also found that one way to fix this problem is to use `user_latent_factor = Lambda(lambda x: tf.gather(user_matrix, tf.to_int32(x)))(user_input)`, but it's totally not an elegant way.